# Writing a dynamic Shader Pipe using OpenGL ES for a graphics engine

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm not sure if this is the correct term for it, but what I believe I'm trying to do is write a "pipe" of sorts for GLSL shaders on OpenGL ES 2.0. The idea is that this will be a handy component, if you will, which will go into the graphics pipe of my engine. My target platform is Android. I'd like some criticism regarding my design methodology behind this. In a nutshell, it seems like I'm faced with either creating a dynamic processing pipe which I'm just able to simply specify some settings and add values to, or having a minimal amount of automation and still keeping things relatively low level in terms of how much code is being written, and what the code is doing.

**The Details**

So far, my design methodology is as follows:

- Shader files are stored in the assets folder
- Java acts as a frontend, gets all shader files, and stores each one in a Shader object which contains information about the type of shader and the original shader source.
- Java then sends shader data to C++ in an array of these custom shader objects (i.e., *not* the OpenGL shader objects - yet), which are then parsed by the JNI.
- Afterward, the JNI sends the shader sources obtained via Java to a ShaderHandler class singleton, which holds a multidimensional `std::vector< std::vector< GLuint > >` for each type of shader (one for vertex, one for fragment, one for texture, etc.).

  - The ShaderHandler class does the compiling and linking of the shader objects into a programmable interface, once this has been accomplished, it channels much of the heavy lifting by extending its functionality to component classes which act as ShaderVariable handlers, via assigning values to them dynamically. For instance, once could simply specify a value/vector/matrix/whatever and the number of indices to modify, and pass that into the ShaderVariable handler. As soon as that SVH gets, it it stores it in a `std::map`, using the name of the variable as its identifier.
- When prompted to, these SVH objects (which are stored in a vector that resides in the ShaderHandler class) essentially *bind* the attributes and uniforms of whatever values exist in their std::maps, dynamically.

Some of the memory allocated is done through pointers, but, admittedly, most of this consists of the stack. I'm wondering if I should look into more dynamic memory allocation for this, as on an Android phone I would imagine a stack overflow could be very, very achievable with a methodology like this for a somewhat ambitious game with good graphics and the like.

Thoughts?

Comment: Exactly what problem do you aim to solve with this?

Comment: I aim to basically create a higher level abstraction interface which will save me *lots* of code in the future. The idea is that I'd like to be able to use the components I've created to simply specify a few arguments, and let the rest be done by the parser. If I wanted to render 3 spheres and have them collide with each other, for example, a system such as this would mitigate the required code for that. This is meant to be a graphics engine for the Android NDK, primarily.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I do something *very* similar with the graphics engine I work on.  The primary difference is that I'm doing everything on the C++ side and nothing (not a thing) on the Java side, which eliminates the JNI barrier.

Also, I've abstracted a few things as I do the same thing for OpenGL and DX9.

A few Tips:

- Vertex and Fragment shaders are separate files that are linked into a shader 'Program'.  Specify the program by folder and then search the folder for 'gles2.vert' and 'gles2.frag'.  In the future search for 'gles3.vert'/'gles3.frag' or 'dx11.vert'/'dx11.frag', etc..
- Have embedded 'default' shaders embedded in your source code.  This allows you to replace a missing vert/frag shader with a default.  You won't believe how many times the vertex shader is the default shader
- Before you link, bind your attribute locations.  Have a predefined list of names/types for the attributes.  It's ok if the shader doesn't use the attribute.
- After you link, grab the uniform locations and store them in your SVH.  std::map will allow you to specify a Functor that makes it case insensitive.  Also, it's easy to deduce the uniform types at runtime for simple type checking when setting values.
- Also, use glUniform1i after link to set sampler locations.  This is to make `texN`[0..N] uniforms point to the right sampler.
- SVH will have default values, or you will need a flag that determines if the user has set a value.
- Keep an State for the program.  The Program might have an std::map, but you will need to have a user state for user set uniforms.  This state makes it so you can use the same shader program with different uniform values.  The user state doesn't need the uniform locations as they will be resolved by the program svh map.  This lets you aggregate uniform values without draw calls.

Drawing

- explicitly bind and unbind samplers, don't do it automatically.  It's nice to be able to load a color_lut on sampler[1] and run sampler[0] as the texture for multiple different calls.
- After you bind the program, but before you draw, resolve and set the uniforms from the user state using the locations in the program state.

Keep the shader program, the sampler and the geometry unaware of each other.  This agnostic approach lets you perform some cool effects, for instance the color_lut shader I mentioned earlier works because the geometry doesn't explicitly set the shader and doesn't wipe out the sampler state. It's a stackable material system.

There is one check I perform, that's to see if sampler0 is set before I bind the shader program, and if it is (and no shader is explicitly set) then I will set a default texturing shader.  If no textures are present (and if set to the default texturing shader) I will fall back to a simple color shader.  If the shader program is ever not [null, defaultTex] then I don't mess with it.

Don't be afraid to ask any other questions.